# Get JQuery change events from childs with wildcard on parent selector

Tags: jquery, events, listener, wildcard, selector

I try to get all elements with a given wildcard and check events from child input containers.

How is this possible?

```
$('*[class^="discount"] input').on('change', function() {});
```

from

```
<li class="x discountValue y"> 
    <some various elements>
        <input class="checkbox" ...>
    </some various elements>
</li>
```

Comment: Just FYI, your class attribute selector doesn't work because the value begins with `x`, not `discount`. There's plenty of hacky solutions you could use to work around this, such as filtering on the `classList` on all the elements, but the best solution would be to put a specific class on all the elements you want to retrieve. Then you can just select them directly without having to write any band-aid logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes that start with `discount` including classes that contain `discount`

```
$("[class^='discount'],[class*=' discount']")
```

Comment: Thank you. This works: $('[class^="discount"],[class*=" discount"]').on("change", "input", function () {

Comment: Yes, that will work. I've only emphasised on the selector as per your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Can you try this code here:**

you can found it use the function the **parents()**, the jquery **parents()** give to you find the until parent when it's found then the stop founding. you can also learn more about selector parent here https://api.jquery.com/parents/

```js
$('*[class="discount"] input').on('change', function() {
  $(this).parents('.parent').addClass("found");
  console.log("founded");
});
```

```css
.parent.found {
   background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="discount">
    <input type="text" vlaue="">
  </div>
</div>
```